# Reference for: the fundamental group of a simplicial complexes is in general undecidable

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

For my thesis I would like to cite the fact that there is a simplicial complex whose fundamental group is undecidable. However, I can not find a reference (or a cluster of references) which explicitly state so.

Alternatively I could also re-prove this fact using the Theorem of Novikov-Boone. I know how to show the existence of CW-complexes with undecidable fundamental groups, using the Theorem of Novikov-Boone. This is fairly easy. But for me it requires quite some work to achieve the same for simplicial complexes.

For some perspective: my focus is on logic and discrete mathematics. I have very basic knowledge of algebraic geometry. I also have to stick to the setting of simplicial complexes.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to say that a group is undecidable. Since you mention the theorem of Novikov-Boone, I expect you mean a group whose word problem is undecidable.

Comment: Yes, I am a bit sloppy with my formulation. I think to be very precice one has to work with edge path groups as I do not see how the fundamental group is algorithmically accessible. I guess then the actuall question would be: is there a resource that shows that the edge path group of a simplicial complex is undecidable (seen as a subset of $V^{\ast}$, where $V$ is the vertex set of the simplicial complex)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of properties of $G$: if you can construct a CW complex that has $G$ as a fundamental group then you can also construct such simplicial complex. It follows from the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** Every CW complex X is homotopy equivalent to a simplicial complex,
>   which can be chosen to be of the same dimension as X , finite if X is finite, and
>   countable if X is countable.

The theorem with a proof can be found in Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", Theorem 2C.5, page 182. I recommend reading whole Hatcher if you are new to algebraic topology.

Comment: Thank you freakish, I did not know that Hatcher treats simplical complexes as well. After the comment of Derek Holt, I actually have to think about how the fundamental group of a CW complex can be seen as a discrete object. The thing is that we are not just talking about groups but about representations of groups. I guess I have to read more.